# JSON Parsing Error Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm trying to Parse the following `JSON` string to a `JSONArray`. (Apologies, I can't get it to format properly here)

```
 {"count":30,"recipes":[
    {"publisher":"Closet Cooking","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/35120","title":"Bacon Wrapped Jalapeno Popper Stuffed Chicken","source_url":"http://www.closetcooking.com/2012/11/bacon-wrapped-jalapeno-popper-stuffed.html","recipe_id":"35120","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/Bacon2BWrapped2BJalapeno2BPopper2BStuffed2BChicken2B5002B5909939b0e65.jpg","social_rank":100.0,"publisher_url":"http://closetcooking.com"}
    ,{"publisher":"Closet Cooking","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/35169","title":"Buffalo Chicken Chowder","source_url":"http://www.closetcooking.com/2011/11/buffalo-chicken-chowder.html","recipe_id":"35169","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/Buffalo2BChicken2BChowder2B5002B0075c131caa8.jpg","social_rank":100.0,"publisher_url":"http://closetcooking.com"},{"publisher":"All Recipes","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/34889","title":"Zesty Slow Cooker Chicken Barbeque","source_url":"http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Zesty-Slow-Cooker-Chicken-Barbecue/Detail.aspx","recipe_id":"34889","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/4515542dbb.jpg","social_rank":100.0,"publisher_url":"http://allrecipes.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/46906","title":"Roast Chicken","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2012/08/roast-chicken/","recipe_id":"46906","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/roastchicken2feab.jpg","social_rank":100.0,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/46996","title":"Cajun Chicken Pasta","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2011/09/cajun-chicken-pasta/","recipe_id":"46996","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/cajun0676.jpg","social_rank":100.0,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/47194","title":"Chicken Parmigiana","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2009/10/chicken-parmigiana/","recipe_id":"47194","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/4024225151_5f477f16caabf9.jpg","social_rank":100.0,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"Healthy Delicious","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/0c2e90","title":"Baked Chicken and Spinach Flautas","source_url":"http://www.healthy-delicious.com/2012/03/baked-chicken-and-spinach-flautas/","recipe_id":"0c2e90","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/205xNxchickenandspinachflautas2296f.jpg.pagespeed.ic.RNEW9wsRU.jpg","social_rank":100.0,"publisher_url":"http://www.healthy-delicious.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/47064","title":"Chicken Tortilla Soup","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2011/01/chicken-tortilla-soup/","recipe_id":"47064","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/5337400468_d5892f3a03_od5cd.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999999994,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"Cookin Canuck","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/ed141a","title":"Hearty Chicken Stew with Butternut Squash & Quinoa Recipe","source_url":"http://www.cookincanuck.com/2011/11/hearty-chicken-stew-with-butternut-squash-quinoa-recipe/","recipe_id":"ed141a","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/ButternutQuinoaStewSquareSmall300x3005144.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999999994,"publisher_url":"http://www.cookincanuck.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/46982","title":"Broccoli Cheese Soup","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2011/11/broccoli-cheese-soup/","recipe_id":"46982","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/broccolicf92.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999999993,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/47070","title":"Chicken and Dumplings","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2010/12/chicken-and-dumplings/","recipe_id":"47070","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/5258969545_eeb0c35356_o7eee.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999999993,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"All Recipes","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/28924","title":"Slow Cooker Chicken Taco Soup","source_url":"http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Slow-Cooker-Chicken-Taco-Soup/Detail.aspx","recipe_id":"28924","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/9843414ab7.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999999945,"publisher_url":"http://allrecipes.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/46947","title":"Chicken with Mustard Cream Sauce","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2012/02/chicken-with-mustard-cream-sauce/","recipe_id":"46947","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/chickenmustarde587.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999999929,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"All Recipes","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/34810","title":"Yummy Honey Chicken Kabobs","source_url":"http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Yummy-Honey-Chicken-Kabobs/Detail.aspx","recipe_id":"34810","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/1184378c8a.jpg","social_rank":99.9999999999988,"publisher_url":"http://allrecipes.com"},{"publisher":"All Recipes","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/4500","title":"Braised Balsamic Chicken","source_url":"http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Braised-Balsamic-Chicken/Detail.aspx","recipe_id":"4500","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/532125a2ff.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999999856,"publisher_url":"http://allrecipes.com"},{"publisher":"All Recipes","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/2495","title":"Baked Honey Mustard Chicken","source_url":"http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Baked-Honey-Mustard-Chicken/Detail.aspx","recipe_id":"2495","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/2334b48b.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999999491,"publisher_url":"http://allrecipes.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/47264","title":"Ranch Style Chicken","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2009/01/ranch-style-chicken/","recipe_id":"47264","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/3214830317_3470607769fad0.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999999457,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/47167","title":"Homemade Chicken and Noodles","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2010/01/homemade-chicken-and-noodles/","recipe_id":"47167","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/4302390134_8a04478597_oc153.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999999358,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"Closet Cooking","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/35168","title":"Buffalo Chicken Chili","source_url":"http://www.closetcooking.com/2012/04/buffalo-chicken-chili.html","recipe_id":"35168","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/Buffalo2BChicken2BChili2B5002B9548b7d71737.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999999191,"publisher_url":"http://closetcooking.com"},{"publisher":"What's Gaby Cooking","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/9eb23b","title":"Cheddar Jalapeno Chicken Burgers with Guacamole","source_url":"http://whatsgabycooking.com/cheddar-jalapeno-chicken-burgers-with-guacamole/","recipe_id":"9eb23b","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/CheddarJalapenoChickenBurgerswithGuacamole4fdb.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999998766,"publisher_url":"http://whatsgabycooking.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/46933","title":"Chicken Florentine Pasta","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2012/04/chicken-florentine-pasta/","recipe_id":"46933","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/florentineebc6.jpg","social_rank":99.9999999999312,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/46882","title":"Bowtie Chicken Alfredo","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2012/12/bowtie-chicken-alfredo/","recipe_id":"46882","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/chickenalfredoc9c5.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999993057,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/46980","title":"Pork Roast with Apples and Onions","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2011/11/pork-roast-with-apples-and-onions/","recipe_id":"46980","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/porkroastapplese1e2.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999991239,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"Jamie Oliver","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/aad814","title":"Perfect roast chicken","source_url":"http://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/chicken-recipes/perfect-roast-chicken","recipe_id":"aad814","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/390_1_1350903747_lrg0b42.jpg","social_rank":99.999999999897,"publisher_url":"http://www.jamieoliver.com"},{"publisher":"Closet Cooking","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/35629","title":"Tequila Lime Grilled Chicken Club Sandwich with Guacamole and Roasted Jalapeno Mayo","source_url":"http://www.closetcooking.com/2012/05/tequila-lime-grilled-chicken-club.html","recipe_id":"35629","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/Tequila2BLime2BGrilled2BChicken2BClub2BSandwich2Bwith2BGuacamole2Band2BRoasted2BJalapeno2BMayo2B5002B0617b8b60d15.jpg","social_rank":99.9999999997356,"publisher_url":"http://closetcooking.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/46979","title":"Pumpkin Soup","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2011/11/pumpkin-soup/","recipe_id":"46979","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/punkin3f44.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999972584,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"Simply Recipes","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/36043","title":"Classic Baked Chicken","source_url":"http://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/classic_baked_chicken/","recipe_id":"36043","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/bakedchickenc300x2002b69c2e8.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999969124,"publisher_url":"http://simplyrecipes.com"},{"publisher":"The Pioneer Woman","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/2fdcab","title":"Pastor Ryan\u2019s Chicken Tikka Masala","source_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2009/06/chicken-tikka-masala-by-pastor-ryan/","recipe_id":"2fdcab","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/chickentikkamasalac65c.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999945585,"publisher_url":"http://thepioneerwoman.com"},{"publisher":"Picky Palate","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/484d98","title":"Crock Pot Pesto Ranch Chicken Thighs","source_url":"http://picky-palate.com/2012/09/20/pesto-ranch-crock-pot-chicken-thighs/","recipe_id":"484d98","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/CrockPotPestoRanchChickenThighs1text1300x248ca0b.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999941502,"publisher_url":"http://picky-palate.com"},{"publisher":"All Recipes","f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/26851","title":"Roast Sticky Chicken Rotisserie Style","source_url":"http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Roast-Sticky-Chicken-Rotisserie-Style/Detail.aspx","recipe_id":"26851","image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/464580296.jpg","social_rank":99.99999999899647,"publisher_url":"http://allrecipes.com"}]}
```

I've been using this line of code: `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(rawJSON);` with `rawJSON` being the variable name.

When this line runs, I get a `JSONException`, but I can't figure out why. Any help would be apprectiated

EDIT: Code where JSON is parsed

```
  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient((new BasicHttpParams()));
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);


        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;

        try{
            org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                sb.append(line);

            }
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {
            try{if(inputStream !=null) inputStream.close();}catch (Exception f){}
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: you have a JSONObject not a JSONArray

Comment: Please post the code where you try to format the json

Comment: post logcat and json parse... please. You json is a JSONObject and the only array is "recipes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert a JSONObject intro a JSONArray.
First, take the JSONObject. After that take the JSONArray.

Having in `result` the json as string:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("recipes");
```

Comment: Yep, that worked! The API reference said it returned an array, and my JSON isn't strong. Thanks!